# Application-wide request hooks in Flask. How to implement?

Tags: python, flask, architecture

Is it ok to define a shared request hook inside the application factory?

```
def create_app(config_name):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    db.init_app(app)
    csrf.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    babel.init_app(app)

    @app.before_request
    def before_request_callback():
        if request.view_args and 'locale' in request.view_args:
            if request.view_args['locale'] not in app.config['SUPPORTED_LOCALES']:
                return abort(404)
            g.locale = request.view_args['locale']
            request.view_args.pop('locale')

    from . app_area__main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    from . app_area__admin import admin as admin_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix='/admin')
```

Comment: The `Blueprint` also have `before_app_request` decorator.

Comment: @stamaimer do you mean I should reference it in my blueprints from a separate module / have a shared func to decorate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just register a function with `before_app_request` in your main(app_area_main) blueprint. For example:

```
@main_blueprint.before_app_request
def before_app_request():
    pass
```

All request pass to the app will invoke that function.

Check this [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_app_request) about the api of Blueprint in Flask.

Comment: Hm, would that be enough - to just register it for **main_blueprint** only (to omit the registration for other blueprints)? Does the *'even if outside of a blueprint'* line from the docs imply that there's a one-time registration?

Comment: Yes, Because the name of the decorator is `before_app_request` instead of [`before_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_request).